# Error starting spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.7.3.RELEASE in PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

i'am using dataflow-server-cloudfoundry (spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.7.3.RELEASE version) to deploy my Stream app to our PCF.

However the start-up of the server application is failing with the below error:

2018-12-12T09:43:55.013+01:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/config/features/TaskConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'taskService' parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskLauncher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'taskLauncher' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'version' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration$EarlyConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.zafarkhaja.semver.Version]: Factory method 'version' threw exception; nested exception is reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientException: HTTP request failed with code: 404.
2018-12-12T09:43:55.013+01:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Failing URI: /v2/info

Comment: reactor.netty.http.client throw HTTP request failed with code: 404.
It try to connect to cf_api to get the Version but it failed with 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry#458](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/issues/458). The user had an incorrect value set for `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL` property.